# Open google maps and return user's selected location

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a requirement,I need users to open google map and select a location/place. The app will receive the selected location and save it in its database. I know i can open a map using the map android activity, but that activity is fairly limited, it does not have the needed search feature. So, can I open google maps using an intent to capture user's selection. Is there any mechanism to notify my app when a user selects a location on google maps app opened from an intent.

Comment: You can embed a google map object in your activity, and add a search bar to the top.  When the user enters some search criteria, you can call a Google API to search for similar locations, then receive an array of possible matches and plot them on the map.

Comment: Yeah this is one of the ways to do it, but this would require a bit of coding. I was thinking, if there was a way to hook/ listen to the google map app to get the selected coordinates. For example, when a user select a location in a google map website, the location is appended to the URL, like this: https://www.google.com/maps/place/The+Foodist/@24.9062702,67.034303,20z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x3eb33fb00e564c23:0xb58683773d9612a9!8m2!3d24.9057031!4d67.0339809